# SLURM with python multiprocessing give inconsistent results

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, slurm

We have a small HPC with 4*64 cores, and it has SLURM installed in it.

The nodes are:

```
sinfo -N -l
Mon Oct  3 08:58:12 2016
NODELIST    NODES PARTITION       STATE CPUS    S:C:T MEMORY TMP_DISK WEIGHT FEATURES REASON              
dlab-node1      1     dlab*        idle   64   2:16:2 257847        0      1   (null) none                
dlab-node2      1     dlab*        idle   64   2:16:2 257847        0      1   (null) none                
dlab-node3      1     dlab*        idle   64   2:16:2 257847        0      1   (null) none                
dlab-node4      1     dlab*        idle   64   2:16:2 257847        0      1   (null) none
```

To test the SLURM i wrote a little script in python with multiprocessing:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
def func(i):
    print(n_procs)

n_procs = int(os.environ['SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE'].split('(')[0]) * int(os.environ['SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES'])
p = multiprocessing.Pool(n_procs)
list(p.imap_unordered(func, [i for i in range(n_procs*2)]))
```

I use the following batch `sh` script to run it with SLURM

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH -p dlab                # partition (queue)
#SBATCH -N 2                      # number of nodes
#SBATCH -n 64                     # number of cores
#SBATCH --mem 250                 # memory pool for all cores
#SBATCH -t 0-2:00                 # time (D-HH:MM)
#SBATCH -o slurm.%N.%j.out        # STDOUT
#SBATCH -e slurm.%N.%j.err        # STDERR

python3 asd.py
```

As i would expect this would print `128` `256` times to the STDOUT file.

However if i run this multiple times i get very different amount of lines (they all contain `128` which is correct)

For the first run i got 144 lines, the second time i got 256 (which is correct) and the third time i get 184.

What is the problem? Should i investigate something inside the configuration of SLURM, or there is something wrong within python `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From sbatch man page:

> SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE
>
> Count of processors available to the job **on this node**.  Note the select/linear plugin allocates entire nodes to jobs, so the value indicates the total count of CPUs on the node.  The select/cons_res plugin allocates individual processors to jobs, so this number indicates the number of processors on this node allocated to the job

As highlighted, the variable will only return the number on cpus allocated in the node where the script is running. If you want to have an homogeneous allocation you should specify `--ntasks-per-node=32`

Also, bear in mind that multiprocessing will not spawn processes in more than one node. If you want to span multiple nodes you have a nice documentation [here](https://rcc.uchicago.edu/docs/tutorials/kicp-tutorials/running-jobs.html#multiprocessing)

Comment: Even if i get only one node from that variable, the variable in my pythone code will be a constant 1. After that the multiprocess should do two "iterations" and print two 1s. This does not explain the inconsistent number of results.

Comment: The inconsistent results may be due to a non homogeneous allocation. If the first node is allocated 30 procs and the second node 34 you will get a different result than if both nodes get 32 procs

Comment: Why is that? All nodes do the same thing, so it should not matter which node it is allocated to. You mean that one node prints, but one node does not? It makes no sense to me

Comment: No, only the first node runs the script. Python does not know how to use the other node. For that you need to use some module for multi-node multiprocessing or MPI

Comment: It still does not  explains it. `multiprocessing` i use is a python module. Why would a core behave differently from all others? If this is true then you cant run a script on a not even number of cores as you will get different results from the "non symmetrical" nodes.

Comment: And btw with --ntasks-per-node=32 i get the same different number of results

Comment: What version of slurm are you using? I can not run your code with 15.08. It is failing in the parsing of the SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE. If you want to have the total number of tasks you can use `SLURM_NTASKS`.

`mutiprocessing` is just starting processes in the node running the script. Running the `asd.py` inside slurm does NOT mean it is running on all the nodes. Just running `python asd.py` will run the python script in the first node and the second node will remain idle.

Comment: The version is `slurm 15.08.7`, and `SLURM_JOB_CPUS_PER_NODE` returns `64(x2)` as a string if i use 2 nodes, that is why is use the `split`. After trying with `--ntasks-per-node=32` nothing happend, same error. Even if i only use 1 node i get different results. If i just simply run the script without `SLURM` using 64 cores with multiprocessing i get the desired results. This indicates that the error is inside `SLURM`

Comment: It seems then that the problem may be in the buffer of the stdout. Try adding: `import sys` and `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print(n_procs)`

Comment: Interesting, that actually solved the problem, thanks a lot!